# SQL query to compare budget to actual expenses

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to build a query comparing budget to actual expense items.
The budget table has a single record per month/category on the first day of the month whereas the expense table has many records throughout the days of the month.

My desired result:

| YEAR | MONTH | category | budgetAmt | sumExpenseAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | daily | 100 | 49 |
| 2021 | 1 | monthly | 42 | 87 |
| 2021 | 2 | daily | 101 | 36 |
| 2021 | 2 | monthly | 55 | 82 |

What I'm getting:

| YEAR | MONTH | category | budgetAmt | sumExpenseAmt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | daily | 100 | 85 |
| 2021 | 1 | monthly | 42 | 169 |
| 2021 | 2 | daily | 101 | 85 |
| 2021 | 2 | monthly | 55 | 169 |

The amounts in "sumExpenseAmt" are wrong AND they're repeating. 
(85 is the sum of all expense-daily items (jan + feb): 40 + 9 + 32 + 4)
(169 is the sum of all expense-monthly items (jan + feb): 83 + 4 + 75 +7)

MY SQL:

```
SELECT YEAR( "b"."date" ) AS "Year"
, MONTH( "b"."date" ) AS "Month"
, "b"."category"
, "b"."budgetAmt"
, SUM( "e"."expenseAmt" ) AS "sumExpenseAmt"
FROM "budget" AS "b"
JOIN "expense" AS "e" ON "b"."category" = "e"."category"
GROUP BY YEAR( "b"."date" ), MONTH( "b"."date" ), "b"."category", "b"."budgetAmt"
```

table: budget

| date | category | budgetAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | daily | 100 |
| 2021-01-01 | monthly | 42 |
| 2021-02-01 | daily | 101 |
| 2021-02-01 | monthly | 55 |

table: expense

| date | category | expenseAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 | daily | 40 |
| 2021-01-07 | daily | 9 |
| 2021-01-08 | monthly | 83 |
| 2021-01-25 | monthly | 4 |
| 2021-02-01 | daily | 32 |
| 2021-02-05 | daily | 4 |
| 2021-02-15 | monthly | 75 |
| 2021-02-20 | monthly | 7 |

I've tried aggregating the expense table with a query and feeding the result into my initial SQL query, but that gives me the same result.

query: qry_summary_expense

| date | category | budgetAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | daily | 49 |
| 2021-01-01 | monthly | 87 |
| 2021-02-01 | daily | 36 |
| 2021-02-01 | monthly | 82 |

```
SELECT YEAR( "b"."date" ) AS "Year"
, MONTH( "b"."date" ) AS "Month"
, "b"."category", "b"."budgetAmt"
, SUM( "e"."expenseAmt" ) AS "sumExpenseAmt" 
FROM "budget" AS "b" 
JOIN "qry_summary_expense" AS "e" ON "b"."category" = "e"."category" 
GROUP BY YEAR( "b"."date" ), MONTH( "b"."date" ), "b"."category", "b"."budgetAmt"
```

Comment: GROUP BY in a subqueries _before_ joining.

Comment: You need to join by month of expense too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd join on both month and category

```
select year(b.date) as year,
month(b.date) as month,
b.category,
avg(budgetAmt) as budgetAmt,
sum(expenseAmt) as expenseAmt
from expense e
join budget b
on (month(b.date) = month(e.date)
and b.category = e.category)
group by year(b.date), month(b.date), b.category
```

Comment: This query cause double the budget as you have mapping between Budget and expenses with one to many mapping

Comment: You're right. I updated it to avg(budget) Thanks. Although, it could be argued if budget needs to be aggregated in the first place and just add to group by without any aggregation in this case

Comment: This works! Thank you!
I tried both Avg(b"."budgetAmt") as well as in the GROUP BY section.
I scoured my SQL book's chapters on JOINs but multiple ON conditions aren't mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables on `category` AND month (using `eomonth` (end of month) does the trick).

```
SELECT Year(Eomonth(e.date))  AS year,
       Month(Eomonth(e.date)) AS month,
       e.category,
       Avg(budgetamt)         AS budgetAmt,
       Sum(expenseamt)        AS sumExpenseAmt
FROM   expense e
       INNER JOIN budget b
               ON Eomonth(e.date) = Eomonth(b.date)
                  AND e.category = b.category
GROUP  BY e.category,
          Eomonth(e.date);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0d59ee331607abd8d0313747d90e1d82)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it does work, but what's the benefit of Eomonth()?
Using the same query, I get the same answer without it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use left or right joins based on your need.

```
select b.Year,b.Month,b.category,Budget, Expenses
from(
    Select year(date) [Year] ,month(date) [Month] ,category,sum(budgetAmt)  Budget
    from budget
    group by year(date),month(date),category
    ) b 
 Join
   (
    Select year(date) [Year] ,month(date) [Month] ,category,sum(expenseAmt) Expenses
    from expense
    group by year(date),month(date),category
   ) e
on b.Month = e.Month and b.Year = e.Year and b.category = e.category
```

Another Approach Using EOMONTH Function:

```
select Year(a.dates) Year ,month(a.dates) Month,a.category,sum(Budget)     Budget, sum(Expenses) Expenses
from(
     Select EOMONTH(date) dates,category,sum(budgetAmt)  Budget
    from #budget
    group by EOMONTH(date),category
    ) a 
Join
   (
    Select EOMONTH(date) dates,category,sum(expenseAmt) Expenses
    from #expense
    group by EOMONTH(date),category
   ) b
 on a.dates = b.dates and a.category = b.category
 group by Year(a.dates),month(a.dates),a.category
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach, generating tables within the FROM and JOIN clauses.
It does work but is there a benefit for building the budget table within the FROM clause instead of directly in the top SELECT clause?